# Xcode 4: target dependency for specific build configuration?

Tags: xcode4

I have 2 library targets I'd like to each be built in Debug and AdHoc exclusively, referenced by a single target which builds the app.

Unfortunately I can only add "Target Dependencies" in project settings for the entire project.  Even though I've added linker flags for each target in their respective build config, I can see that both targets are being built every time, even though they aren't explicitly referenced by OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS.  Any way around this?